# Spring URL when both controller and method do not have @RequestMapping values

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm being asked to take over a piece of code. Being that I am not an seasoned Spring developer, I have a question on what is the URI when both the controller and method does not specify a value for @RequestMapping.

For example, the code looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class FooController {

    @RequestMapping
    public String getThis(String input) {
        return "This";
    }
}
```

So what is the URL that I need to access the getThis method?

Comment: check the `web.xml` or `spring-config.xml` files to see if there is a default controller being specified or if the named controller (in your case `FooController` is being named or mapped to a specific URL/URI

Answer (score 0):

Sometime back i also had the same doubt. Am thinking that `Controller` without `@RequestMapping` will throw an exception (am not sure).

For method case:

If you don't have any values in `@RequestMapping`, method will listen on `Controller` path and you dint specify any `method` so it will listen `ALL HTTP Methods`.

Answer (score 0):

Your method will not be reachable and you can see this via a warning message from Spring like :

> 21:57:50.608 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping -
>   Rejected bean name
>   'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor':
>   no URL paths identified

If you need to have this method in the root URL, you need to use the value "/" instead of nothing.